# navigation.navigate does not work on one of useEffect();

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am developing a code and always need the user to enter the application to check if there is an update, if there is to send the user to an information screen. But for some reason when I use navigation.navigate ('update') it doesn't work, but console.log ("oi"); above it works. What happens **is normal** is that last useEffect() executes the navigation.navigate ('Menu'); In the console does not show any kind of error.

Code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function verifyVersion() {
        await api.post('/version', {
            version: 'v1.0'
        }).then((response)=>{
            console.log("oi");
            navigation.navigate('update');
        });
    }
    verifyVersion();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    async function autoLogon() {
        if(await AsyncStorage.getItem("Authorization") != null){
            await api.post('/checkToken', null, {
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'EST ' + await AsyncStorage.getItem("Authorization") }
            }).then((res)=>{
                navigation.navigate('Menu');
            }).catch(function (error){
                if(error.response.data.showIn == "text"){
                    setShowInfo(true);
                    if(error.response.data.level == 3){
                        setColorInfo(false);
                    }else{
                        setColorInfo(true);
                    }
                    setInfoText(error.response.data.error);
                }else{
                    setshowBox(true);
                    if(error.response.data.level == 3){
                        setcolorBox(false);
                    }else{
                        setcolorBox(true);
                    }
                    setboxText(error.response.data.error);
            }
            });
        }
    }
    autoLogon();
}, []);
```

Routes:

```
    import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import read from './pages/read';
import Menu from './pages/Menu';
import Resultado from './pages/Resultado';
import NoConnection from './pages/NoConnection';
import update from './pages/update';
const Routes = createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator({
        Login,
        Menu,
        read,
        Resultado,
        NoConnection,
        update
    })
);

export default Routes;
```

Comment: Are you using `react-navigation` or `react-native-navigation` ?

Comment: `when I use navigation.navigate ('update') it doesn't work` Are you sure you have a route named `update`  ?

Comment: react-navigation

Comment: Yes, i have a route, i add route in the code

Comment: try changing `update` to `Update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Write the navigate function call in setTimeOut for 500ms. it works
> fine for me

```js
useEffect(() => {
   ....
   setTimeOut(() => navigation.navigate('Dashboard'), 500);
}, []);
```

Comment: Please add more explanation.

Answer (score -1):

In react-navigation, screen mounting works differently from react component mounting. You need to use a focus listener like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
  if (!someCondition) navigation.navigate('someScreen');
});
return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

More on the topic can be found [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle) and [here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/581#issuecomment-847614656)

Comment: didn't work in my case